# Enable unmanaged c++ debug with error 'hresult=0x8013134d. errorcode=0x0' with .Net debug

Tags: c#, c++, .net, debugging

When I enable unmanaged c++ debug with managed C# project in one solution in VS2010, usually, I get the messagebox popup '**HRESULT=0x8013134d. Errorcode=0x0**'. I have no choice but to kill the process devenv.exe.
    I searched some web pages all that showed the cause are interop cannot be supported (CORDBG_E_INTEROP_NOT_SUPPORTED). Is there any method could solve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a restriction in 64-bit code for VS2010.  Debugging the 32-bit build of your solution is the recommended approach.  If that is a show-stopper then make the C++ project your startup project, set the start exe to your compiled C# program, so you get pure unmanaged debugging.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, yes, I set the 32-bit to unmanaged C++ project and set 32-bit managed C# project in the solution, but it still alarm the message box. Please note the c++ project just has been compiled as .dll files to server the c# project.